# What is the cause for 'Segmentation fault (core dumped) '

Tags: c

I wrote a program to find the prime factors of a number using recursion. I am getting an run time error. What is the cause?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main () {
    int num , i = 2 ;
    printf ( " Enter the number to find the prime factors\n ") ;
    scanf ( "%d", &num ) ; 
    printf ( " The factors are :\n") ;
    pf ( num , i ) ;
}

int pf ( int num , int i){
    if ( num % i == 0 ){
        if ( checkprime(i) == 1){
            printf ( " %d " , i ) ;
            num = num / i ;
        }
    }
    if ( num > 1 ){ 
        i++ ; 
        pf ( num , i ) ;
    }
}

int checkprime ( int i){
    int j ;
    if (i==2)
        return 1 ;
    for ( j = 2 ; j < i ; j++ ){
        if ( (i % j) == 0 )
            return 0 ;
        else 
            return 1 ; 
    }
    if ( i==j )
        return 1 ;
}
```

Sample run:

```
Enter the number to find the prime factors
 12
 The factors are :
Segmentation fault (core dumped)enter code here
```

Comment: You recursion never stops : pf is called with 2, num is set to 6, pf is called with 3, num is set to 2, then it is called endlessly with i incremented without updating num

Comment: A prime factor can appears more than once (12=2×2×3)

Comment: You should be able to simply walk through your own logic, and you will immediately see that `pf` will call itself endlessly.  In the process, it should be obvious what you need to change to stop the infinite recursion.  Also, recursion is inappropriate for this problem.  Use a loop instead.

Comment: There is no return statement in `int pf(int, int)` function. Check it

Comment: That code shouldn’t even compile. If it does, you should turn on more warnings. On gcc/clang/icc, I generally use `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a learning exercise you want to solve on your own, so I won’t be writing code for you.  (If you try to plug the sample code here into your program without refactoring, it won’t work.)

In the spirit of teaching you to fish, the first thing you should do is compile without optimization, with debugging symbols, and with all warnings turned on.  On gcc/clang/icc, the flags for that will be something like:

```
-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -g
```

This code should not even compile.  You’re repeatedly falling through to the end of a function that does not `return` the `void` type, yet falls through with no `return` statement.  Not only that, you define `pf()` and `checkprime()` after they are called with no prototype!  That’s not the only bug, but let’s start there.

You’re technically supposed to have a `return` from `main()`, too, but so many programs don’t that the C committee just gave in and said it’s optional.

A good next step to catch a bug is to load the program in a debugger, put a breakpoint on the function you want to debug, and single-step through it.

When you do this, you see that the program goes into an infinite loop if you give it, let’s say, `4`, and if you do give it an answer that terminates, such as `pf(1, 2)`, it will fall through all the `if` blocks and never reach a `return` statement.

So you need to debug your algorithm, but first, you need to make sure that every path through your function reaches a `return` statement.  (You might also, if you don’t actually need a return value, declare `void pf(int, int)`.

One way I like to do this (but doesn’t seem to be common in C) is to write `if`-`else`-`return` with the `?` operator, such as:

```
 return (num <= 1)     ? 1 :              // No more factors.
        (num % i == 0) ? pf( num/i, i ) : // Prime factor, with possible multiplicity.
                         pf( num, i+1 );  // Not a factor.  Keep looking.
```

This of course doesn’t work here because it never prints the factors.  (It’s based on functional-style code that isn’t supposed to have side-effects like doing I/O.)  One way to fix it would be to rewrite with `if`/`then`/`else`.  Another is to store the factors in a data structure such as a dynamic array or linked list, and return that.  Another is to print before the complex `return`.  Another is to have the branch that should print a factor call a mutually-recursive function that prints and then calls `pf()`.  A really ugly hack that you shouldn’t do is to use the comma operator.  Pick the one you like the best.

This has the advantage of being tail-recursive, so it might go into an infinite loop but will not cause a stack overflow.

If you don’t like this style, another approach that some shops use to prevent this bug from happening is to write the function with nested `if` blocks that set a variable like `int to_return = UNSET;`.  Then, every branch sets `to_return` to the proper value and you can finish with something like

```
if (foo)
  to_return = 1;
else
  to_return = f(i);

asseert(to_return != UNSET);
return to_return;
```

That way, the compiler ensures that you’re returning from a valid branch, or if you do forget to set a return value along some path, crashes and tells you where and why, not “Segmentation fault (core dumped).”